Optimizing sum of $k$ positive integers with the product $m$
The product of $k$ positive integers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ is $m$, I'm wondering how to find the minimum and maximum of $\sum_{i=1}^kx_i$. For the maximization problem, in order to exclude the trivial case $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_{k-1}=1$ and $x_k=m$, I would add the constraint that $1$ may only appear once as a factor. However, to minimize the sum, it is allowed for $1$ to appear multiple times.
Based on my observations on some small numbers, I believe that we can optimize the sum as follow:
For maximizing the sum, we chose $x_1$ to be $1$ and choose $x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_{k-1}$ to be the smallest possible divisors of $m$ and $x_k=\dfrac m{x_2 x_3\ldots x_{k-1}}$.
For minimize the sum, we try to select $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ be close to $\sqrt[k]m$ as much as possible (as the result of the AM-GM inequality).
I wrote a script to for $k=2,3,\ldots,10$ and $m=2^2\times3^2\times5^1\times7^2\times11^2=1067220$. The results are presented in the table:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{k} & \approx \sqrt[k]{1067220} & \text{Minimum Sum} & \text{Maximum Sum} \\
\hline
2 & 1033.06 & 2068 \, (990, \, 1078) & 1067221 \, (1, \, 1067220) \\
3 & 102.19 & 307 \, (98, \, 99, \, 110) & 533613 \, (1, \, 2, \, 533610) \\
4 & 32.14 & 129 \, (28, \, 33, \, 33, \, 35) & 266810 \, (1, \, 2, \, 2, \, 266805) \\
5 & 16.06 & 83 \, (11, \, 14, \, 15, \, 21, \, 22) & 88943 \, (1, \, 2, \, 2, \, 3, \, 88935) \\
6 & 10.11 & 62 \, (7, \, 9, \, 10, \, 11, \, 11, \, 14) & 29656 \, (1, \, 2, \, 2, \, 3, \, 3, \, 29645) \\
7 & 7.26 & 53 \, (5, \, 6, \, 6, \, 7, \, 7, \, 11, \, 11) & 5945 \, (1, \, 2, \, 2, \, 3, \, 3, \, 5, \, 5929) \\
8 & 5.67 & 51 \, (3, \, 3, \, 4, \, 5, \, 7, \, 7, \, 11, \, 11) & 870 \, (1, \, 2, \, 2, \, 3, \, 3, \, 5, \, 7, \, 847) \\
9 & 4.68 & 51 \, (2, \, 2, \, 3, \, 3, \, 5, \, 7, \, 7, \, 11, \, 11) & 151 \, (1, \, 2, \, 2, \, 3, \, 3, \, 5, \, 7, \, 7, \, 121) \\
10 & 4.01 & 52 \, (1, \, 2, \, 2, \, 3, \, 3, \, 5, \, 7, \, 7, \, 11, \, 11) & 52 \, (1, \, 2, \, 2, \, 3, \, 3, \, 5, \, 7, \, 7, \, 11, \, 11) \\
\hline
\end{array}
This example shows I might be right about the first observation but wrong about minimizing the sum (since, for $k=8$, no factor of $6$ is used), but interestingly it appears that arithmetic mean of the factors, are usually very close to $\sqrt[k]m$ (however the use of "very close" is subjective):
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{k} & \approx\sqrt[k]{1067220} & \approx\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i \\
\hline
2 & 1033.06 & 1034 \\
\hline
3 & 102.19 & 102.33 \\
\hline
4 & 32.14 & 32.25 \\
\hline
5 & 16.06 & 16.6 \\
\hline
6 & 10.11 & 10.33 \\
\hline
7 & 7.26 & 7.57 \\
\hline
8 & 5.67 & 6.38 \\
\hline
9 & 4.68 & 5.67 \\
\hline
10 & 4.01 & 5.2 \\
\hline
\end{array}
I'm wondering if there is a method to solve this optimization problem systematically.

You may wish to consult the paper (SciHub) entitled:$$ $$Krause, E.F. (1996). Maximizing the product of summands; minimizing the sum of factors. Mathematics Magazine, 69(4), 270-278.

A systematic approach is to use dynamic programming.  Let the value function be $$V_\min(k,m,\ell)=\min\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i: \prod_{i=1}^k x_i = m \land 1 \le x_1 \le \dots \le x_k \le \ell\right\}.$$
We want to compute $V_\min(k,m,m)$.
The boundary condition is
$$V_\min(1,m,\ell) = \begin{cases}m &\text{if $m \le \ell$},\\ \infty &\text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$
For $k>1$, conditioning on the value $x_k=d$ yields recursion
$$V_\min(k,m,\ell) = \min_{\substack{d|m:\\d \le \ell}} \left\{d + V_\min(k-1,m/d,\min(d,m/d))\right\}.$$
For maximization, the boundary condition is
$$V_\max(1,m,\ell) = \begin{cases}m &\text{if $m \le \ell$},\\ -\infty &\text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$
And the recursion for $k>1$ is
$$V_\max(k,m,\ell) = \max_{\substack{d|m:\\2 \le d \le \ell}} \left\{d + V_\max(k-1,m/d,\min(d,m/d))\right\}.$$
The optimal results match your table.
